# Slides using jquery animation

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, slide

I want to create a simple slide for a site. Here I am trying to call the function **slideShow** infinitely. But the function works till the point where animate function ends. But when trying to set CSS property again it doesn't work . Also iteration is not working. Please point out where i am making the mistake . Thanks in advance.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function slideShow() {
        $('#image1').delay(2000).animate({
            opacity: 0
        }, 5000);

        $('#image2').delay(2000).animate({
            opacity: 1
        }, 5000);

        //After this point nothing seems to be working.
        $("#image1").css("opacity", "1");
        $("#image2").css("opacity", "0");
        slideShow();
    };

    slideShow();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You are changing the CSS property of image before the animate() has completed it's duration of 5 seconds.

Call the function again but after 5 seconds. This works perfectly:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function slideShow() {
        $('#image1').animate({opacity: 0,}, 5000);
        $('#image2').animate({ opacity: 1}, 5000);
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#image1").animate({opacity: 1,},5000);
        $("#image2").animate({opacity: 0,},5000);
        slideShow(); // call it recursively but after 5 seconds
        }, 5000);      
    };
    slideShow();
});
```

Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

Replace the last `slideShow();` with this, for a 10 second repeat:

```
setInterval(function () { slideShow(); }, 10000);
```